# Java JMenuItem add a border after the second menuItem

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I was trying to add some menu and wondering how can I add a border after the second menuItem

Just like this

[Image Here](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/1361/menunz.png)

here is my code

```
jmb = new JMenuBar();
jmb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(43,30));

jmMenu = new JMenu("Menu");
jmSettings = new JMenu("Settings");

jmiMenu = new JMenuItem("Add User"); 
jmiMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.print("Rod click menuItem");
    }
});
jmiMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,25));
jmiExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
jmiExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.print("Rod click exit");
    }
});

jmb.add(jmMenu);
jmb.add(jmSettings);

jmMenu.add(jmiMenu);
jmMenu.add(jmiExit);

add(jmb);
```

Answer (score 5):

That is not a border, that is called a "separator" within the menus. Add this after the 2nd menuitem

```
    jmMenu.addSeparator();
```

That will put the line across the menus, and will give you the output as in the image.

Comment: I dont have 15 repu. sorry

Comment: That's alright, I don't help people for the fame, I do it for the help! :) Just like Jesus helped the multitudes of people with his miracles!